# is it possible to initialize static variable with lambda?

Tags: c++, static, lambda

I've tried this:

```
#include <map>

int main() {

  static std::map<int,int> myMap = [](){
    std::map<int,int> myMap;
    return myMap;
  };

}
```

error:

```
<stdin>: In function 'int main()':
<stdin>:8:3: error: conversion from 'main()::<lambda()>' to non-scalar type 'std::map<int, int>' requested
```

And yes, I know that I can create another 'normal' function for it ant it works but lambdas cannot initialize objects in that way.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible.

```
static std::map<int,int> myMap = [](){
  std::map<int,int> myMap;
  return myMap;
}();
```

Note the `()` at the end. You are assigning `myMap` to a lambda, but you really want to assign it to the result of the lambda. You have to call it for that.

Comment: I think you missed the `->std::map<int,int>` within the lambda declaration.

Comment: @theV0ID, the return type isn't necessary on a lambda if it can be deduced from the return statement (as it can here).  (Side note: If the parameter list is empty, as it is here, it is also optional.  Thus, this could be written using: `static auto myMap = []{ return std::map<int,int>(); }();`)

Comment: Yes it is. Tested with gcc 4.8, running 5 threads and a static variable within the clousure. `[](){ static int i = 0; i += 1; assert(i == 1); }`